# Verhältnis zwischen Menge eines Produktes und Menge präparierter Objekte — "Effizienz"/"Wirksamkeit" oder doch etwas anderes?

Tags: single-word-request

Ich suche nach einem Wort, das das Verhältnis zwischen der Menge des Produktes (z.B. Wachses) und Menge von Autos, die ich mit diesem Produkt beschichten kann. Ist das die *Wirksamkeit* oder *Effizienz*? Oder doch was anderes?

Comment: Denkbar ist auch ein Wachs, das nicht wirkt (nicht hält), dann ist die Wirksamkeit nicht gegeben. Erst wenn die Menge, die man für eine wirksame Beschichtung braucht, in Betracht gezogen wird, kann man die Effizienz beurteilen. Oft gibt es auch viele, interessierende Parameter: Wie viel muss ich auftragen, wie lange hält es, wie gut lässt es sich auftragen...

Comment: @userunknown Hmm. Nehmen wir mal an, ich verkaufe ein Produkt, von dem man zum Polieren eines Autos einen Fingerhut voll braucht, für 10€. Meine Konkurrenz hat ein Produkt, von dem man für dasselbe Auto einen Eimer voll braucht, verkauft aber den Eimer für 9€. Dann möchte ich in meinem Hochglanz-Faltblatt natürlich "Ergiebigkeit" und nicht "Effizienz" hervorheben.

Comment: @tofro: Keine Einwände. Die Frage dreht sich aber um Wirksamkeit vs. Effizienz, nicht um Ergiebigkeit und Effizienz. Ergiebigkeit hat erst user2238 ins Spiel gebracht. Und Du bringst einen Preis ins Spiel, der in der Frage so nicht da ist. Meist redet man ja von Ergiebigkeit in Bezug auf eine Packungsgröße. Wenn der Supermarkt einen Liter Spüli für 40 Spülen und einen halben Liter Konzentrag für 50 Spülen verkauft, dann ist das Konzentrat ergiebiger, auch wenn es mehr pro Spüle kostet. Aber beim Verhältnis ml/Spüle ist das Konzentrat vorne.

Comment: @userunknown Lies die Frage nochmal. Vor allem die letzten 4 Wörter

Comment: @tofro: Versprochen!

Answer (score 6):

Die Begriffe Wirksamkeit / Effizienz oder auch Wirkungsgrad beziehen sich in hohem Maße auf die Qualität, weniger auf die Quantität. Ein Produkt ist effizienter / wirksamer als ein anderes, wenn sich (an deinem Autowachsbeispiel) Dauer oder Stärke des Schutzes unterscheiden, Auftragungsmenge aber identisch sind.

Wenn du ausdrücken willst, dass du mit einer Flasche von Produkt 1 mehr Autos in gleichem Maß behandeln kannst, als es mit Produkt 2 möglich wäre, würde ich von **"Ergiebigkeit"** sprechen.

Beispiele:

Ergiebigkeit (Quanitität):

> Produkt 1 ist ergiebiger als Produkt 2. Ich kann mit der gleichen
>   Menge mehr Autos wachsen.

Wirksamkeit (Qualität):

> Produkt 1 ist wirksamer/effizienter als Produkt 2. Bei gleicher Auftragungsmenge hält die  Wachsschicht länger und schützt den Lack besser vor UV-Strahlung.
>
> Produkt 1 ist wirksamer/effizienter als Produkt 2. Der Lackschutz ist gleich, aber es muss weniger aufgetragen werden.

Comment: Basierend auf deinem Absatz gilt aber auch die Umkehrung: Ein Produkt is effizienter/wirksamer, wenn ich mit **weniger** Auftragungsmenge den **gleichen** Effekt erziele.

Comment: Ja und Nein. In dem Fall schaust du auf Qualität. Die Unterscheidung bezieht sich auf "Qualität" und "Quantität". Dass die gleiche Menge für mehr Autos reicht, muss nicht heißen, dass der Lackschutz vergleichbar ist. Es kommt m.E. auf die Art der "Messwerte" an.

Comment: Das sage ich ja: Wenn ich bei weniger Menge den **gleichen Effekt** erziele. Eine Größe muss man ja konstant halten, sonst gibt es keine Vergleichbarkeit. Und sowohl bei Effizienz als auch Ergiebigkeit geht man davon aus, dass der erzielte Effekt derselbe ist.

Comment: Ich finde, *Ergiebigkeit* ist das exakt treffende Wort. Wirksamkeit und Effizienz sind was anderes: Eine Kopfschmerztablette kann sehr "wirksam" sein - Das hat aber weder was mit Effizienz noch mit Ergiebigkeit zu tun. Auf der anderen Seite kann ein Produkt sehr effizient (im Sinne von "wirtschaftlich") sein, weil es wenig kostet und trotzdem *hinreichend* wirkt.  Deshalb muss es noch lange nicht *sehr* wirksam oder ergiebig sein.

Comment: Effizienz ist nicht gleich Effektivität. Eine effektive Maßnahme bewirkt was sie soll, muss aber nicht effizient sein. Eine effiziente Maßnahme steht in einem guten Verhältnis zum Aufwand. Um Flugzeugabstürze zu verhindern kann man Flugzeuge abschaffen. Das ist eine effekttive (=wirksame) Methode. Zur Beurteilung, ob Brot verschimmelt ist, kann man kurz dran schnüffeln, was sehr effizient ist, aber nicht so effektiv, wie eine mikrobiologische Analyse im Labor, die aber nicht mehr effizient ist (teurer als ein frisches Brot).

Answer (score 2):

Wenn aus dem Kontext klar hervorgeht, welche konkrete Eigenschaft des Produkts tatsächlich genau gemeint ist, können **umgangssprachlich** verschiedene Wörter verstanden werden (und zum Beispiel auch in der Werbung vorkommen).

Beispielsweise findet man im Duden Band 8 einige Synonyme, die allerdings nicht alle auf den Fall „Anzahl der Autos, die mit einer gewissen Menge des Produkts behandelt werden können“ übertragen werden können:

> Auswirkung, Durchschlagskraft, Durchsetzungskraft, Effektivität, Effizienz, Erfolg, Geltung, Kraft, Leistung, Schlagkraft, Stärke, Wirkung, Wirksamkeit, Wirkungskraft

Dagegen sind **fachsprachlich** die Begriffe *Wirksamkeit* und *Effizienz* gewöhnlich genauer definiert. So findet man in der internationalen Norm ISO 9000, in der viele Begriffe zum Qualitätsmanagement festgelegt sind, die folgenden Definitionen:

> **Wirksamkeit**
>
> Ausmaß, in dem geplante Tätigkeiten verwirklicht und geplante Ergebnisse erreicht werden

sowie

> **Effizienz**
>
> Verhältnis zwischen dem erreichten Ergebnis und den eingesetzten Ressourcen

Somit beschreibt der Begriff *Effizienz* tatsächlich genau das gesuchte Verhältnis zwischen der Anzahl der beschichteten Autos (dem erreichten Ergebnis) und der Menge des Wachses (den eingesetzten Ressourcen).

Comment: Effizienz: Nicht notwendigerweise: "Ergiebigkeit" sagt, ob ich einen Eimer oder eine Fingerspitze des Materials brauche, unabhängig davon, was ein Eimer bzw. eine Fingerspitze des jeweiligen Produktes *kostet*. "Effizienz" wird im allgemeinen in einem wirtschaftlichen (d.h erster Linie finanziellen) Kontext betrachtet und würde die Kosten sehr wohl mit einbeziehen (u.A. - Wahrscheinlich auch, wie lange man für die Anwendung braucht usw., also eher eine Gesamtkostenbetrachtung). Leider sagt uns der OP nicht, was davon gemeint ist.

Answer (score 0):

Es kommt ein bisschen auf die Sichtweise an. Du kannst sagen, ein Produkt hat eine höhere Reichweite oder Ergbiebigkeit, wenn Du ausdrücken möchtest, dass Du z.B. mit der gleichen Grundmenge mehr Autos behandeln kannst, wobei der erzielte Effekt der gleiche ist.

Beispiel:

> Politur A und Politur B werden beide in einer 200ml Dose geliefert. Mit B kann ich aber 5 Autos mehr behandeln (bei gleichem Schutz-/Glanzeffekt) als mit A, daher ist B ergiebiger. Eine Dose B hat eine höhere Reichweite.

Es gilt aber auch der umgekehrte Schluss.

> Da ich sowohl von A als auch von B 200ml habe, offensichtlich aber pro Auto weniger B benötige um den gleichen Effekt zu erzielen, ist B wirksamer/effizienter als A.

Comment: "Reichweite" finde ich hier nicht so passend. Ich würde tatsächlich "Ergiebigkeit" vorziehen.

Comment: *Wirksamkeit* ist nicht *Effizienz/Wirkungsgrad*, sondern *Effektivität*.Im vorliegenden Fall ist der Unterschied nicht gut hervorzuheben, aber beispielsweise sind die negierten Begriffe *ineffizient* und *unwirksam/ineffektiv* absolut nicht synonym.